# Vagrant, Flask — App not running on 10.10.10.10, 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, flask, ip, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm running an app on my local box via Vagrant. The Python/Flask app launches and prints:

`* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader`

I found this https://github.com/makersquare/student-dev-box/wiki/Using-Vagrant-for-Development#testing-web-based-applications-in-vagrant
which suggests that Vagrant apps run on `10.10.10.10` (not `127.0.0.1`), but when I navigate to that IP address (port 5000), I get the same result: "This webpage is not available".

Question: my app is running, but on what IP address? I can't seem to find it. Do I need to modify some configuration files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jedwards yes. I tried 10.10.10.10:5000 and 127.0.0.1:5000 (and just plain ole localhost:5000 for kicks and giggles).

Comment: How are you running the app inside Vagrant?

Comment: @tmthyjames If you find the answer helpful, please mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: @sjudǝʊ sorry about that! Your answer def helped. Thanks! I accepted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways how you could run flask web app on virtual machine (managed by vagrant). I think that following approach is quite flexible, because you don't have to deal with different ip address. Also it looks like you are developing on a host machine.

There are 2 things you need to configure. In **VagranFile**, you need configure port forwarding.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # use default box
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # forward port guest machine:5000 -> host machine:5000
  # port 5000 is default for flask web app
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000
end
```

Then, on virtual machine, you should start flask app on ip `0.0.0.0` which means that web app will serve for any IP address. More on this topic -> [flask doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/) section **Externally Visible Server**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

That's it. You should be able to connect to `http://localhost:5000`

Answer (score 1):

In the file where you call `app.run`, it should be

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=...
```

In the host OS, navigate to the IP of the guest with the port that you're running the app from.

Answer (score 1):

sjudǝʊ is right but it took me 4 hours to figure out he forgot to mention you also must run:

`vagrant halt` and then `vagrant up`

in order for your update to the vagrant file to actually take affect

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Flask and python you do not need to configure vagrant file or no change required in the python script. Just run the flask with --host

```
flask run --host=192.168.10.80
```